# upstart conf file not being copied

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, upstart, cgroup

- Ubuntu 14.04 chroot
- apt-get install cgroup-lite
- `invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/cgroup-lite not found.`

If I download source files (tarball), decompress it, there is a cgroup-lite.upstart file. If I copy it to `/etc/init.d/cgroup-lite` and try to install again, it works.

Why is that script not being copied when installing with apt-get?
It is also happening with dpkg and deb package.

Ubuntu Official repositories

Full log:

```
Preparing to unpack .../cgroup-lite_1.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking cgroup-lite (1.9) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up cgroup-lite (1.9) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/cgroup-lite not found.
dpkg: error processing package cgroup-lite (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
    cgroup-lite
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Upstart was not properly configured or started (I was on a chroot).
So installation scripts did not detected that and did not copy the upstart script to /etc/init/cgroup-lite.conf

To avoid this issue
    touch /etc/init/cgroup-lite.conf
    apt-get install cgroup-lite
    rm /etc/init/cgroup-lite.conf

It will use /etc/init.d/cgroup-lite instead